# Getting the data from a JSON when using a multi select option in JQuery and assigning the values

Tags: jquery, json

Hoping someone can help me with read JSON and an error I am getting.
I have a Select Multiple option. The value has to be more than one parameter like this

```
 <select id="my-select" name="character" multiple="multiple">
    <option value='{"id":"#final.id#","text":"#final.name#"}'>#final.name# 
    </option>
 </select>
```

A user can select multiple options as you would expect.

Error: If I select more than one option then I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token, in JSON at position 70

This is what is produced

```
{"id":"41","text":"Apples"},{"id":"130","text":"pears"}
```

Not sure why this is a problem but it is. When I select one option the output in the console looks like this

```
key is id
value is 41
key is text
value is Apples
```

I used this code to display it

```
var appleList  = $('select#my-select').val();
var finalapple = JSON.parse(appleList);


$.each(finalapple,function(i,v){
    console.log("key is " + i)
    console.log("value is " + v)
})
```

I would like to write a for loop

```
for(var i=0;i<trustList.length;i++)
{ }
```

Which append the value to different parts of a string. For example:

```
var mystring = ' I like' + 'text'+ 'which have the id =' + 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an onchange event to know when the user actually selects something. Right now you get the values of `my-select` on page load (which no values are selected yet) so `appleList` is null.

A onchange event can also help you loop through the selected values. `$(this).val()` the `this` refers to the select option element and jQuery is smart enough to get you the selected values through the `.val()` function.

```js
$("select#my-select").on("change", function() {
  $.each($(this).val(), function(i, v) {
    console.log("key is " + i);
    console.log("value is " + v);
    // parse the option value from json into an object
    var obj = JSON.parse(v);
    
    console.log("value id is " + obj.id);
    console.log("value text is " + obj.text)
    var mystring = "I like " + obj.text + " which has the id = " + obj.id;
    console.log(mystring);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="my-select" name="character" style="width: 100px" multiple="multiple">
    <option value='{"id":"41","text":"Apples"}'>Apples
    </option>
    <option value='{"id":"22","text":"Pear"}'>Pears
    </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Actually, the OP is getting the values correctly; it was a little hard to tell with the formatting, so the first paragraph is irrelevant. The rest of the answer is great though!

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem. Had a couple other issues but managed to figure them out and now all is working as expected and no more errors.